# Is their anyway I can replace the filename to MD5

Tags: php, file-upload, md5

I am working on a small upload script. But, when the file is uploaded to the upload directory. The file name is the same name of the file uploaded. Is it possible to rename it to random digits like MD5.
Thanks!

```
<?php

require 'header.php';

?>

<center>
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is not an image.";
      //  $uploadOk = 1;
    }
}
?>
<br>
<?php
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo " Sorry, the file already exists or";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
?>
<br>
<?php
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "your file was not uploaded correctly. Please try again or contact support!.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
</center>
```

Comment: MD5 is not random digits, it is a message digest - so then same uploaded file-content will produce the same md5 ...

You can get the MD5 of a file like [this](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.md5-file.php)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to generate the new file name? That way you will be sure each file uses unique names.

Comment: How would you suggest I do that?

Comment: When you move the file and ser the destination name, you can use that function to generate an unique name. You can prepend the original file name to that uniqid, for example, and that way you will keep track of the file instead of completely changing its name.

Comment: in your pastebin code you have this line: $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); - you need to call uniqid instead of using basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])

Comment: @citywall the problem with that is he will remove the file extension from the name if he completely replaces it. He should get the file base name, generate a new name with `uniqid($basename)` that will prepend the base name to the `uniqid` and then append the extension. Then use that whole name as the target name.

Comment: @Mindastic I kind of assumed that to be self-explanatory, but I guess it goes to show that we must never assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to rename it.

It's hard to give you too much more information, since you haven't posted any code. To generate the file name, you can use `uniqid()` if you don't need the string to be truly random. If you do need it to be truly random, you need a cryptographically secure function like `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`

Example:

```
$randomString = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20);
$path_parts = pathinfo($tmpFileName);
move_uploaded_file($tmpFileName, $path_parts['filename'] . '-' . $randomString . $path_parts['extension']);
```

This generates a random string, then rebuilds the file name using that string. If the upload was name, for example, `lolcats.gif`, your renamed file might be something like `lolcats-3hf98jfd89W04kLq9PrR.gif`.

Comment: How would you suggest I do that?

Comment: But `move_uploaded_file()` is going to overwrite the existent file if both files share the same name and i think that is what he doesn't want to do.

Comment: @ChrisPantelli It's hard to give you too much more information, since you haven't posted any code. To generate the file name, you can use `uniqid()` if you don't need the string to be truly random. If you do need it to be truly random, you need a cryptographically secure function like `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

Comment: @Mindastic I didn't say he should do it without checking whether he would be overwriting an existing file. I have tried to give him a little more guidance.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses I was able to do it with the 'uniqid()'.